# How to write a test unit for a service that returns a promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, promise, karma-jasmine, deferred

Here is my factory in my app.js

```
  app.factory('userInfoFacrory', ['$http' , "$q", function($http,$q){
    return {
           getNames:function(){
            var differed  = $q.defer();
            $http.get("http://localhost/ang/api/v1/users/names")
            .success(function(data) {
                differed.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(msg) {
                differed.reject(msg);
            });
            return differed.promise;
          }
    }
  }])
```

I use this factory in my controller like bellow , and it works fine :

```
 app.controller('mainController', ['$scope','userInfoFacrory','$log', function($scope,userInfoFacrory,$log){

    var promise = userInfoFacrory.getNames();
    promise.then(function (data) {
        $log.info(data); // I get my data correctly here
    }, function (msg) {
        $log.error(data);
    })
}])
```

And here , I've tried to write a test unit , with karma-jasmine

```
describe('userInfoFacrory', function() {
var  factory ,$rootScope,$scope,$q,onTaskComplete , promise;

       beforeEach(function() {
        module("testApp");
        inject(function ($injector) {   
            $q = $injector.get("$q");
            factory = $injector.get("userInfoFacrory");
            $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            promise = factory.getNames(); // this function comes from my factory which returns a promise 
        });      
      });

      it('should return a promise', function() {
          // This test will pass , so no error so far 
         expect(typeof promise.then).toEqual('function');
      });
});
```

But I can't figure out how to test to so if my promise will have my data ( that comes from my api ) or not , any suggestion would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
it('should return a promise resolved with the http response data if the http request is successful', inject(function($httpBackend) {

    var expectedData = 'fake data';
    $httpBackend.expectGET('http://localhost/ang/api/v1/users/names').respond(expectedData);
    var promise = factory.getNames();
    var actualData;
    promise.then(function(result) {
        actualData = result;
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(actualData).toEqual(expectedData);
}));

it('should return a promise rejected with the http response data if the http request is in error', inject(function($httpBackend) {

    var expectedData = 'fake data';
    $httpBackend.expectGET('http://localhost/ang/api/v1/users/names').respond(400, expectedData);
    var promise = factory.getNames();
    var actualData;
    promise.catch(function(result) {
        actualData = result;
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(actualData).toEqual(expectedData);
}));
```

Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/NfO6KXWLs1QT5HG8MK0J?p=preview

Note that your code is correct, but doesn't really leverage the chaining capabilities of promises. It could simply be written as

```
getNames: function() {
    return $http.get("http://localhost/ang/api/v1/users/names")
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function(response) {
            return $q.reject(response.data);
        });
    };
}
```

Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/C5x8wRYCQ0wetjozEd0a?p=preview

Comment: Error: Unexpected request: GET http://localhost/ang/api/v1/users/names
 No more request expected

Comment: And what exactly $httpBackend does here ? I mean I want to run the api call in my factory to see if it works , I dont want to call to my Api in the unit test ,

Comment: You should remove the call to the service inside beforeEach(). $httpBackend is described in the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend